# Disable manual entries

Tags: toggl

Is it possible to disable manual entries in toggl timetracking or better require manager approval for each manual entry?

If that’s not possible, what time tracking alternative would allow for this?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].